# Set project JRE build path entry to 'JavaSE-1.7'

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am trying to make a connection with MySQL database, but when I use `PreparedStatement`, eclipse returns `Set project JRE build path entry to 'JavaSE-1.7'`
Yes, I have changed the compiler version to 1.7, but Android works only with 1.5 and 1.6 right?
How can I connect to my data base?
This is my actual method to connect:

```
private ArrayList<String> sql = new ArrayList<String>();
private Connection con;
  public String getUsuario(String...parametros) throws SQLException {
            sql.add("SELECT "+parametros[1]+"FROM users WHERE `usuario_id` = "+parametros[0]+";");
               for (String string : sql) {
                try (PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(string);
                        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()) {
                        while(rs.next()) {
                            System.out.println(rs.getString("usuario_senha"));
                        }
                    }
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax that was introduced in Java 7. You need to change it to the Java 6 way. You could do something like this:

```
PreparedStatement stm = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
for (String string : sql) {
    try {
        stm = con.prepareStatement(string);
        rs = stm.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("usuario_senha"));
        }
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
        if (stm != null) {
            stm.close();
        }
    }
}
```